Zendesk Trigger to add User custom field data to Ticket custom field
I have a custom User field name Oilsoft ID. I have a custom Ticket field named Oilsoft ID. I want to inherit the User Oilsoft ID into the the ticket Oilsoft ID upon ticket update if there is not already a Ticket Oilsoft ID present.
I have tried to do this with a trigger as follows:
Meet ALL conditions:
Ticket>Ticket      Is   Updated
Ticket>Oilsoft ID   NOT present
Actions:
Ticket>Oilsoft Id    {{ticket.requester.custom_fields.oilsoft_id}}
But the Action simply put the the literal “{{ticket.requester.custom_fields.oilsoft_id}}” in the Ticket Oilsoft ID field.
This seems to indicate that placeholders can't be used here.
So how else could I achieve this functionality?

Text fields do not support placeholders. You need to use the API, but you risk triggering race condition.
I would recommend using ZIS flow for safe execution as it is guaranteed to run after the trigger cycle has been completed.

In the meantime, I have achieved the result via Zapier. That said their "Updated Ticket" trigger has up to 2min delay, so not optimal. I will dig into ZIS

While the race conditions are a possibility, many workflows are built upon a ticket firing a webhook and updating itself.  Zendesk has even put in place safeguards to prevent issues.  So you may be able to try the webhook solution first and see if it meets your needs, because it is in fact much easier to set up than a custom ZIS flow.
